# How to group by data of a specific column from csv file and put them all in one row in arff format

Tags: python

I'm very beginner in python programming.I have a csv data file and I want to group by sender in my dataset and get some columns data of the related sender for different rcvTime and keep them all in one row for that sender like being time series data but in arff format.
Here is a part of my data:

```
row number,type,rcvTime,sender,pos_x,pos_y,pos_z,spd_x,spd_y,spd_z,acl_x,acl_y,acl_z,hed_x,hed_y,hed_z
0,2,25207.0,15,136.07,1118.46,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0
1,2,25208.0,15,136.19,1117.14,0.0,0.22,-2.31,0.0,0.14,-1.48,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0
2,3,25208.81,21,152.66,904.56,0.0,0.06,-0.75,0.0,0.18,-2.43,0.0,0.07,-1.0,0.0
3,2,25209.0,15,136.69,1113.79,0.0,0.39,-4.18,0.0,0.15,-1.64,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0
4,3,25209.81,21,152.98,902.59,0.0,0.22,-2.91,0.0,0.12,-1.68,0.0,0.07,-1.0,0.0
5,2,25210.0,15,133.77,1108.01,0.0,0.58,-6.17,0.0,0.16,-1.76,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0
6,3,25210.81,21,153.25,898.68,0.0,0.37,-4.65,0.0,0.11,-1.35,0.0,0.08,-1.0,0.0
7,2,25211.0,15,134.37,1100.75,0.0,0.76,-8.14,0.0,0.18,-1.93,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0
8,3,25211.81,21,153.82,893.0,0.0,0.65,-6.67,0.0,0.25,-2.54,0.0,0.1,-1.0,0.0
9,3,25211.93,27,122.87,892.12,0.0,5.63,0.32,0.0,-1.57,-0.09,0.0,1.0,0.04,0.0
```

For example I want to extract columns data for sender=15 and put them all in one row consequently and then for sender=21 I want to do the same and ... . I appreciate if any one can guid me how can I do it in python.

Comment: Start with reading your data using pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

For column data manipulation, [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) is a wonderful library with tons of documentation ([here is a guide to start](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-complete-pandas-guide-2dc53c77a002)).

For your problem, you can probably use pandas as a first step to get your data [extracted from the csv file](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/pandas_csv.asp), Then you can format the data the way you want using the possibility of [pd.DataFrame](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/pandas_dataframes.asp). Then you can use the [arff library](https://pypi.org/project/arff/) to convert your `pd.DataFrame` to `arff` format (example here: [https://stackoverflow.com...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993918/exporting-dataframe-to-arff-file-python))

Also, it's generally better if you can provide a working example of your code, in that fashion people would know more precisely where problems can lie.

Best of luck !